# Can't move subsites with "Content and Structure"

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, sub-site, modern-pages, content-and-structure

I have enabled the website features content organization and server publishing. However, moving subsites and modern pages does not work.

When I move a subsite, the following error message appears:

Zugriff verweigert.Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Zugriff verweigert. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Zugriff verweigert. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.RenameWeb(StorePath bstrUrl, StorePath bstrNewUrl) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.RenameWeb(StorePath bstrUrl, StorePath bstrNewUrl) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.RenameWeb(StorePath bstrUrl, StorePath bstrNewUrl) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.Update(SPWebUpdateParameters parameters) at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.WebControls.MoveWebs.Move()Fehler beim Vorgang 'Verschieben' aus '/sites/TimeJobWiki/Worker' in '/sites/TimeJobWiki/TIM/Worker'.

---

Further information based on the reply from @Hellofiona_MSFT:

- I'm using **SharePoint Online**
- When I check the permissions for my own user account, I get the following entry, among others:

*Deny; Add and customize pages; Add, change, or delete HTML or Web Part pages, and edit the Web site in an editor compatible with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.*

But I am the **website collection administrator** and in the Admin Center I **allowed the Custom Scripts**, as you can see on the screenshot. After setting these settings I waited longer than 24 hours and tested again without success.

[image: admin center]

However, the following has now come to my attention. When I am on the Office 365 home page and click the SharePoint icon, I am redirected to an overview page. There I see all the SharePoint web pages that I can access.

I am on the page with the URL:
[mycompany name].sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx

If I visit only [mycompany name].sharepoint.com I am redirected to an SharePoint Website.

This seems to be a special website?
When I check my permissions there, I don't get to see the entry that I am not allowed to add and adjust pages. But there I'm only in the owner group and not even a website collection administrator.

On this website, can I **easily move site pages from one subsite to another subsite**? I can't do this in the other website collection (where i have this **weird additional permission**), I'm denied access there.

I cannot test moving subsites on this website collection, because I am not an website collection administrator. However, I assume that it would work.

**This is all very confusing.
What settings do I have to change if activating the Custom Script feature is not the solution?**

Comment: Just a reminder that the points you put up for bounty will disappear into the "ether" if you do not accept an answer:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76137/what-happens-to-your-reputation-if-you-start-a-bounty-and-dont-get-an-answer#76139

Answer (score 1):

What's the account you use to move subsites? Make sure you use site collection administrator and check again.

Whether you use SharePoint server or SharePoint Online?

If you use SharePoint Online, check if the account have the add and customize pages permission which is relevant to the access denied error. This permission depends on the custom script feature. Please refer to [turn scripting capabilities on or off](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f) to see if you have turned on the features.

Note: this feature needs to take up to 24 hours to take effect.

Comment: Hello Hellofiona_MSFT, thank you for your answer. I've answered your questions, please take a look. Maybe you can help me and give me a solution. I would be very grateful, because I am really desperate at the moment.

Comment: run the commend in sharePoint Online management shell: Connect-SPOService;
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false